# wpf how to bind itemsource with CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i write a simpliest demo to bind listbox to CollectionViewSource, here is vm:

```cs
    public class Model
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public CollectionViewSource CollectionViewSource { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Model> Collection { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = GetSource() };
            this.DataContext = this;
            
        }
        // get data 
        private ObservableCollection<Model> GetSource()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Model> models = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
            models.Add(new Model() { Text = "a"});
            models.Add(new Model() { Text = "b"});
            models.Add(new Model() { Text = "c"});
            models.Add(new Model() { Text = "d"});
            return models;
        }
    }
```

xaml:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source=CollectionViewSource.View}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

the result is not correct:

[image]

and if i delete datatemplate,
xaml:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source=CollectionViewSource.View}">
 </ListBox>
```

it will be:

[image]

what's wrong with it? how can i bind my model's property to listbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=CollectionViewSource.View}"
```

sets the string literal "CollectionViewSource.View" as ItemsSource, which you noticed when you omitted the ItemTemplate.

Set the Binding's Path instead. `CollectionViewSource` is a property of the current DataContext.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollectionViewSource.View}"
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it :

```xml
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionViewSource.View}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

it works fine